# How to properly reset navigation to another view

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation

I am resetting the current view with this code

```
NavigationActions.reset({ index: 0, key: null, actions: [ NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Login' }) ] });
```

Some times it works and some time I get a `Signal Sigabrt` error on the `RCTUIManager.m` file in Xcode. I can't figure out when did the problem occur. The error happens in this function

```
- (void)setSize:(CGSize)size forView:(UIView *)view
{
  RCTAssertMainQueue();

  NSNumber *reactTag = view.reactTag;
  dispatch_async(RCTGetUIManagerQueue(), ^{
    RCTShadowView *shadowView = self->_shadowViewRegistry[reactTag];
    RCTAssert(shadowView != nil, @"Could not locate shadow view with tag #%@", reactTag); // ERROR in this line

    if (CGSizeEqualToSize(size, shadowView.size)) {
      return;
    }

    shadowView.size = size;
    [self setNeedsLayout];
  });
}
```

If I delete the code on the function every thing works fine. 
When there is no crashes, the console is always printing a warning

> View #1430 of type RCTView has a shadow set but cannot calculate
>   shadow efficiently. Consider setting a background color to fix this,
>   or apply the shadow to a more specific component.

But I do not have any View using shadow and could not figure out which react-native element is doing it.

Edit:
if I check that shadowView is not null everything works fine

```
if(shadowView){
    RCTAssert(shadowView != nil, @"Could not locate view with tag #%@", reactTag);
    }
```

Is this a Bug in RN ?

Comment: could you please tell me which react native version you are using?

Comment: I am using react-native 0.48.4

Comment: could you please try to put some more information about your project? the screenshot where you are getting error? what are the packages you are using with versions. fill more information then people on SO can understand you problem.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found is to override the router's getStateForAction function and handle the reset.

So you could dispatch something like this:

```
NavigationActions.reset({ index: 0, key: null, actions: { navigateTo: 'Login' }});
```

And handle this case in a custom `getStateForAction` function:

```
const defaultGetStateForAction = YourNavigator.router.getStateForAction

YourNavigator.router.getStateForAction = (action, state) => {
    if (action.type === NavigationActions.RESET && action.actions.navigateTo) {

      const updatedRoutes = [{routeName: action.actions.navigateTo}]

      return {
        ...state,
        routes: updatedRoutes,
        index: 0
      }
    }

    return defaultGetStateForAction(action, state)
}
```

Here you can read more about [React Navigation - Custom Navigation Actions](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/routers/#Custom-Navigation-Actions)