# How to set header options for react navigation v5?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

guys
I wanted to configure header with

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation  }) => {

}
```

I use react navigation v5
Tell me, I understand correctly that now it is possible to get header settings using only option in Stack.Screen?
Exapmle:

```
<Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{
          title: 'My home',
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#f4511e',
          },
          headerTintColor: '#fff',
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
          },
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `navigation.setOptions({ title: 'Updated!' })` in component to modify desired navigation option.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this same problem and it took me a little bit to figure this out. The docs don't have the best example.

According to the docs, you must use setOptions inside of something like useEffect, otherwise you will get a warning.

In this example, a station object is being passed as a param and 'location' is what I want to use as the title. The useEffect also watches to see if the title variable changes, so on a subsequent reload, it will change it out. Otherwise, it will only set the first time.

```
function MyScreen({navigation, route}) {
  const station = route.params.station;

  // update the title on page load
  const title = station.location;
  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      title: title,
    });
  }, [title]);

...
```

Comment: Using useEffect() turned out to be very effective in setting the screen header title

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the navigation options for a screen in the screen component itself with navigation.setOptions
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers#updating-options-with-setoptions