# React native reset navigation after reaching end in navigation

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have implement react native navigation with 4 tabstack. Every tabstack is with multiple pages, When I moved from first page to next page or next stack. It works fine. but when I moved back to first page of the first stack and click on button of the page. it will move to last visited page of the last visited stack. I am not sure why it is happening.
I am putting my navigation code below

```
const stackNavigatorConfiguration = {
  mode: "card",
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    headerStyle: { backgroundColor: Colors.HeaderColor, borderBottomWidth: 0 },
    headerTintColor: "#0055FF",
    headerTitleStyle: {
      fontSize: 20,
      fontFamily: Constants.FontFamily,
      fontWeight: "bold"
    },
    headerBackTitle: null,
    barStyle: { backgroundColor: Colors.HeaderColor}
  }
};

/* User Profile ---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
const profileTabScreens = {};
profileTabScreens[Constants.Screen.MyProfile] = { screen: UserProfileScreen };
profileTabScreens[Constants.Screen.OrderHistory] = { screen: OrderHistoryScreen };


const profileStack = createStackNavigator(
  profileTabScreens,
  stackNavigatorConfiguration
);
profileStack.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
  tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
    <TabBarItem
      icon={Icons.User}
      tintColor={tintColor}
      routeName={navigation.state.routeName}
    />
  ),
  title:"User"
});



/* Cart ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */
const cartsTabScreens = {};
cartsTabScreens[Constants.Screen.OrderPreview] = { screen: OrderPreviewScreen };
cartsTabScreens[Constants.Screen.OrderSchedulePickup] = { screen: OrderSchedulePickupScreen };
cartsTabScreens[Constants.Screen.OrderConfirm] = { screen: OrderConfirmScreen };
cartsTabScreens[Constants.Screen.AddAddress] = { screen: AddAddressScreen };
cartsTabScreens[Constants.Screen.OrderThankyou] = { screen: OrderThankyouScreen };
const cartsStack = createStackNavigator(
  cartsTabScreens,
  stackNavigatorConfiguration
);

cartsStack.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
  tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
    <TabBarItem
      icon={Icons.Cart}
      tintColor={tintColor}
      routeName={navigation.state.routeName}
    />
  ),
  title:"Carts"
});

/*Deal/Service ------------------------------------------------------------------- */
const dealsTabScreens = {};
dealsTabScreens[Constants.Screen.Service] =  { screen:ServicesListScreen };
dealsTabScreens[Constants.Screen.ShopListByService] =  { screen:ShopListByServiceScreen };



const dealsStack = createStackNavigator( dealsTabScreens, stackNavigatorConfiguration);
dealsStack.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
  tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
    <TabBarItem
      icon={Icons.ICCollection}
      tintColor={tintColor}
      routeName={navigation.state.routeName}
    />
  ),
  title: "Services"
});


/* Home Stack------------------------------------------------------------*/

const  homeTabScreens = {};
homeTabScreens[Constants.Screen.Home] = { screen: HomeScreen };
homeTabScreens[Constants.Screen.Vendor] = { screen: VendorScreen };

const homeStack = createStackNavigator( homeTabScreens, stackNavigatorConfiguration);
homeStack.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
  tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
    <TabBarItem
      icon={Icons.ICBadgeHome}
      tintColor={tintColor}
      routeName={navigation.state.routeName}
    />
  ),
  title: "Home",
 
});

/*------------------------------------------------------------*/

const tabScreens = {};
tabScreens[Constants.Screen.Home] = { screen: homeStack };
tabScreens[Constants.Screen.Service] = { screen: dealsStack };
tabScreens[Constants.Screen.Carts] = { screen: cartsStack };
tabScreens[Constants.Screen.MyProfile] = { screen: profileStack };

const mainTab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(tabScreens, {
  initialRouteName: Constants.Screen.Home,
  activeColor: Colors.BottomMenuColor,
  inactiveColor: Colors.Gray,
  barStyle: { backgroundColor: "#fff" }
});

const screens = {};
screens[Constants.Screen.Launch] = { screen: LaunchScreen };
screens[Constants.Screen.Auth] = { screen: AuthScreen };
screens[Constants.Screen.AuthOTP] = { screen: AuthOTPScreen };
screens[Constants.Screen.AuthPassword] = { screen: AuthPasswordScreen };
screens[Constants.Screen.UserRegisterDetail] = { screen: UserRegisterDetailScreen };
//screens[Constants.Screen.OrderHistory] = { screen: OrderHistoryScreen };
//screens[Constants.Screen.MyProfile] = { screen: UserProfileScreen };
screens[Constants.Screen.Home] = { screen: mainTab };

const mainStack = createStackNavigator(screens, {
  initialRouteName: Constants.Screen.Launch,
  activeColor: Colors.AppColor,
  inactiveColor: Colors.Gray,
  labelStyle: Styles.TabbarLabel,
  headerMode: "none"
});

export default createAppContainer(mainStack);
```

Comment: Will [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48459323/react-navigation-tabnavigator-reset-previous-tab-on-tab-change) answer your question?

Comment: How can I add listen to this particular part of the code

Comment: `const mainTab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(tabScreens, {
  initialRouteName: Constants.Screen.Home,
  activeColor: Colors.BottomMenuColor,
  inactiveColor: Colors.Gray,
  barStyle: { backgroundColor: "#fff" },
  listeners:{({ navigation, route }) => ({  tabPress: () => navigation.navigate(route.name)})}
});`

Comment: listen should be in the component, not in the navigator

Comment: Ok, Thanks for reply.

Comment: Did it work for you? if yes, I can add it as an answer.

Comment: currently No. I still searching for answer.