# React Native Drawer and Tab Navigator

Tags: react-native

Currently I have:

```
-Drawer 
--Home (Tab Nav)
   ---ScreenA
   ---ScreenB
   ---ScreenC
--ScreenY
--ScreenZ
```

When I am on ScreenB or ScreenC, and go to one of the other drawer options say ScreenY, then tap the "Home" Drawer option, it takes me back to ScreenC or wherever I left off. Is there a way to make tapping Home take me to ScreenA every time? Hope that makes sense.

Drawer:

```
<Drawer.Navigator
    drawerStyle={{width: "75%"}}
    drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={TabNavigator} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Help" component={ScreenY} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Terms" component={ScreenZ} />
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

Tab:

```
<Tab.Navigator
        tabBarOptions={{
          activeTintColor: colors.blue,
          inactiveTintColor: colors.black,
          style: {},
          tabStyle: {
            
            backgroundColor: "#e0d5f3",
            borderTopWidth: 3,
            borderBottomWidth: 3,
            borderRightColor: "gray",
          },
          labelStyle: {  
            fontWeight: "bold",
          },
          scrollEnabled: false,
        }}
      >
        <Tab.Screen name="Deals" component={ScreenA} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Digital Qs" component={ScreenB} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Samples" component={ScreenC} />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

Comment: Please check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/65502179/8182248

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native Navigation: Reset Stack Navigator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65445398/react-native-navigation-reset-stack-navigator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is relatively simple, you will need to reset the TabNavigator route every time when your user tap on "Home" option.

The solution to [different React Navigation version have been discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48566048/4311268).